# Django: Creating multiple class instances on a single webpage, with Foreign Key dependencies

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I have the following code in my `models.py`:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Participant(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, related_name="participants")
    ...
```

i.e. There are multiple `Participants`, and each `Participant` will be on a single application. (It is defined that each `Application` will have exactly 8 `Participants`).

The intended purpose of this code is that a user will be able to create a new application, on which he/she will name 8 `Participants`. When the `Application` is created, 8 new instances of `Participants` should also be created and linked such that each `Participant` has the newly created `Application` as its Foreign Key.

I am currently struggling to create a form/view that will handle this creation process. I want the user to be a presented a single webpage that presents input forms that allow the user to create a new `Application` (name, etc.), along with 8 new `Participants` (each having a name, grade, etc.)

My current `forms.py` has:

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that edits an application and all of its participants.
    """

    nationality = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = '__all__'
```

But I realize that this does not display to the user what is needed to create 8 new `Participants` with the creation of this `Application`. How can I modify my `forms.py` to include space for the user to create 8 `Participants` with the creation of an `Application`?

The only solution I can come up with is to manually list 8 `Participant` form calls in a single view, but I feel that there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is django [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/)

> A formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the
>   same page. It can be best compared to a data grid. Let’s say you have
>   the following form:

There is also a [ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet)

> Like regular formsets, Django provides a couple of enhanced formset
>   classes that make it easy to work with Django models.

These can be used to create several instances of a given model in a single page. The only trouble is that it has a bit of a learning curve and the user experience isn't as great as what you might get with Angular or React.